# MySQL Sort on Conditional

Tags: mysql

I’m hoping one of the MySQL gurus out there can help with this...

Here’s the table: (some columns removed to keep this simple)

```
+------------------------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------+-------------------------+-----------------
| id       | text                         | is_featured       | featured_order          | featured_start          | featured_end          |
| 1        | This is my first post        |                 0 |                    5000 |                       0 |                     0 |
| 2        | This is my second post       |                 0 |                    5000 |                       0 |                     0 |
| 3        | This is my third post        |                 0 |                    5000 |                       0 |                     0 |
| 4        | FEATURED #3                  |                 1 |                       3 |              1427846400 |            1429488000 |
| 5        | FEATURED #1                  |                 1 |                       1 |              1427846400 |            1428192000 |
| 6        | This is my fourth post       |                 0 |                    5000 |                       0 |                     0 |
| 7        | FEATURED #2                  |                 1 |                       2 |              1427846400 |            1428624000 |
| 8        | This is my fifth post        |                 0 |                    5000 |                       0 |                     0 |
| 9        | This is my sixth post        |                 0 |                    5000 |                       0 |                     0 |
| 10       | This is my seventh post      |                 0 |                    5000 |                       0 |                     0 |
| 11       | This is my eighth Post       |                 0 |                    5000 |                       0 |                     0 |
| 12       | This is my ninth post        |                 0 |                    5000 |                       0 |                     0 |
```

Here’s my current (very simple) query:

```
SELECT id, text
FROM posts
WHERE visible = 1
ORDER BY featured_order ASC, create_date DESC
LIMIT $offset, $limit;
```

This gives me

```
FEATURED #1
FEATURED #2
FEATURED #3
This is my first
This is my second
This is my third
This is my fourth
This is my fifth
This is my sixth
This is my seventh
This is my eight
This is my ninth
This is my tenth
```

BUT You’ll notice that FEATURED #1 and FEATURED #2 have expired timestamps (April 5th and 10th respectively) - FEATURED #3 expires April 20th…

So FEATURES #1 and #2 should fall back in line with the normal posts, and be ordered by their create_date so I would end up with.

```
FEATURED #3
This is my first
This is my second
This is my third
FEATURED #1
This is my fourth
FEATURED #2
This is my fifth
This is my sixth
This is my seventh
This is my eight
This is my ninth
This is my tenth
```

I know I can do an IF statement in MySQL to select on this, I’m just not sure how to do this, HELP??? :-)

The reason the default feature_order is set to 5000 is because the dual order by, that puts them on top and the 5000’s at the bottom.

Comment: please, create an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) and link it in the question, as it will make easier for people to answer the question

Answer (score 2):

An `ORDER BY` doesn't need to operate on column names directly, it accepts an expression. So you can craft an expression to sort those posts with `is_featured` and a future `featured_end` date to be sorted by `featured_order`, and others to sort by `created_date`.

[Here it is in action at SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/15894/1)...

```
SELECT id, text
FROM posts
ORDER BY 
  -- Non-expired, featured posts are sorted by featured_order
  -- Expired ones are just given a high value to sort later
  CASE WHEN (is_featured=1 AND FROM_UNIXTIME(featured_end) >= NOW()) THEN featured_order ELSE 5000 END,
  -- Followed by other column sorts 
  create_date DESC
LIMIT $offset, $limit;
```

In the example, I applied a second sort by `id` because you didn't supply the `create_date` column in your example, but the effect should be the same. And I added a fourth feature (non-expired) to demonstrate that it will sort ahead with the third feature.

Perhaps a more straightforward approach is to apply a similar `CASE` conditional in `SELECT` to force the `featured_order` value of expired features to be 5000, then simply sort on that in the `ORDER BY`. This is a little easier to follow:

```
SELECT 
  id, text, 
  -- A conditional column to force expired features 
  -- to have 5000, the same as non-featured posts
  CASE 
    WHEN is_featured = 1 AND FROM_UNIXTIME(featured_end) >= NOW() THEN featured_order
    ELSE 5000
  END as calc_featured_order
FROM posts
ORDER BY 
  -- Sort on the conditional column
  calc_featured_order,
  -- Then other columns
  create_date DESC
```

[Example in action...](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/15894/19)

Comment: @Alex It doesn't matter because second level of sorting isn't on `featured_order`. It only applies to the non-expired ones so it can really be any number higher than the other non-expired featured ones.

Comment: yes, I agree it is usually doesn't matter. but we have *ORDER BY featured_order ASC, create_date DESC* and OP wrote **and be ordered by their create_date** so if you put `9999999` those records will not be ordered with the regular records by `create_date` but only among themselves

Comment: @Alex Check the sqlfiddle - sub-ordering by `id` is effectively the same as `create_date` would be, and it does work. The 99999 just pushes them out of the featured group, the next order applies normally, no matter what the value. For consistency I'll change it to 5000

Comment: Really, it's because all rows not matching the condition get assigned 99999 (or 5000) entirely irrespective of their `featured_order` value, so they're all grouped together for sub-ordering anyway.

Comment: Yes I see your logic. but to respect original data I would prefer to **CASE WHEN is_featured=0 OR (is_featured=1 AND FROM_UNIXTIME(featured_end) >= NOW()) THEN featured_order ELSE 5000 END**

Comment: This is fabulous, it works flawlessly. I owe you gentlemen a beer if you're ever in Seattle.